# Laravel Route: Controller method not found

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, laravel-4, apache2

I took a copy of my live Laravel 4 app and set it up on an AWS Ubuntu instance.
Here's the same route that works on live site, http://pixcel.com/archivecloud/786531 ,
and the same route with same code (I think) on the EC2 instance

> 54.186.47.148/archivecloud/786531

Error returned is: Controller method not found

**Live site:**

PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Feb 21 2014 07:53:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies

Apache: not sure, it's shared hosting with site5

**EC2:**

PHP 5.4.25-1+sury.org~precise+2 (cli) (built: Feb 12 2014 10:45:30) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

Relevant code:
Route LIVE:

```
 Route::get('archivecloud/{id}', 'CloudHomeController@embed');
```

Route EC2: `Route::get('archivecloud/{id}', 'CloudHomeController@embed');`

Controller LIVE:

```
class CloudHomeController extends CloudBaseController {
public function embed($id){

        $result = CloudFilm::getInstance()->getFilmByEmbedId($id);
        $cliptype = "film";
}}
```

Controller EC2:

```
class CloudHomeController extends CloudBaseController {
public function embed($id){

        $result = CloudFilm::getInstance()->getFilmByEmbedId($id);
        $cliptype = "film";
}}
```

Looks like the Environment variables are empty. Will look this up.

Comment: We're going to need to see the relevant code. Please paste your routes file and the controller in question.

Comment: Are you using the same Laravel version in both systems?

Comment: Rico, I copied the entire project, including the composer file   "laravel/framework": "4.0.*", so yes.

Comment: That may not be enough if you installed some components independently and some of the check your PHP version. As you probably already know you have PHP version mismatch.

Comment: True, PHP 5.3 works, PHP 5.4 doesn't work, I test PHP 5.5 on localhost and it works - so it's hard to go by the PHP version.

Comment: Find out what Apache or webserver `site5` is using that's the only other thing I see different.